# how to query two collections in once with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have two collections like this:

```
var Users = [
    {
        'ID' : 1,
        'NAME' : 'Seth'
    },
    {
        'ID' : 2,
        'NAME' : 'John'
    }
];

var Posts = [
    {
        'ID' : 1,
        'TEXT' : 'blalalalalala...',
        'USER' : 1
    },
    {
        'ID' : 3,
        'TEXT' : 'blalalalalala....',
        'USER' : 2
    }
];
```

How can I get the posts created by Seth without his ID? (Query By NAME : Seth)

Comment: You need to look into client side joining, this question has been asked a number of times and a quick search will get you a lot of info on the subject

Answer (score 1):

If this is your schema, then there is no way of getting the posts for a given user by name in one query. In your application, you would have to perform two queries. The first to get the `ID` given a `NAME` and the second to get the posts given that `USER`. This is referred to in the MongoDB documentation as "manual referencing" and it would work something like this:

```
var id = db.Users.findOne({ "NAME" : "Seth" });
var posts = db.Posts.find({ "USER" : id });
```

If you indeed want to do this with one query, then you will have to look into embedding posts in an array inside the user documents, using [DBRefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) (which you need to be careful with), or in the case of some ODMs like Mongoose, using "[population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)".

**UPDATE:**

Given the new information presented by the OP, in the case where you want to find all posts for users that have not been deleted, and if you don't want to iterate through a large array every time, I would suggest adding a `USER_DELETED` field that can be set to `true` when a user is deleted.

So in the event that a user with `{ "ID" : id }` is deleted, you would run a query as follows:

```
db.Posts.update({ "USER" : id }, { "$set" : { "USER_DELETED" : true } });
```

That would then mark all of the posts for that user as belonging to a user that has been deleted. So when you want to retrieve the posts for all users that are still around, you would run:

```
db.Posts.find({ "USER_DELETED" : { "$ne" : true } });
```

Or you could do something along those lines. If you know that all the documents have a `USER_DELETED` field set to `false` if the user is still around, then you can just query for those that have the flag set to false.

Of course you will still have to transform the old data to follow this pattern, but that can be achieved with a one time operation that consists of:

1. Finding all of the users that have been deleted.
2. Finding the posts for each of those users.
3. Adding the `USER_DELETED` flag for each of those posts.

That should be a better way of approaching the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks, My real question is: I have one collection named Users with 9000 items. the other collection named Posts has 15000 items. sometimes the users will be deleted but the posts won't, I want to get  all items posted by the users who NOT DELETED.

Comment: var Users = [
        {
            'ID' : 1,
            'NAME' : 'Seth',
            'DELETED' : 0
        },
        {
            'ID' : 2,
            'NAME' : 'John',
            'DELETED' : 1000112
        }
    .........
    ];

Comment: If I query all Users NOT DELETED, I will get a super big array. Use the big array to Query the Posts? Look like it's not a good solution for performance. 
Or is there another kind of Schema can do the right query?

Comment: So what does a document for a user that is not deleted look like. Does it simply not have the DELETED field? A solution could be that when you delete a user, then you mark all of his posts with a flag like userDeleted. So that is a write operation that happens once. Then when you retrieve the posts, you can just query those that don't have the flag. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: @Winmain, I updated my answer to reflect the issues you just mentioned. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Winmain, did this answer help? Let me know if any part of it is unclear.